# My UIView isn't rendering

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm new to iOS development, and I'm struggling to understand how the pieces fit together, and how to best use the Interface Builder (yes, I want to use IB *and* understand how it relates to changes in code).

Here's my current scenario:

- I created a class `PageViewController : UIPageViewController`, which I have associated with my "Page View Controller Scene" in IB.  This is the initial view controller.
- I created a class `Page1ViewController : UIViewController`, which I have associated with "Page1 View Controller Scene" in IB.  Also in IB, I have added a `UIView` to that scene, that has an opaque white background and a single label in it.
- In `PageViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method, I do the following:

  `setViewControllers([Page1ViewController()],
       direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, 
       animated: true, completion: nil)`

In both the `viewDidLoad` method of both `PageViewController` and `Page1ViewController`, I have a `println` and both are displaying, so I know they are getting loaded...but when I run my app, I have a blank black screen.

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:

- `PageViewController` has multiple custom pages that I want to design in IB (they are not like the out-of-the-box calendar example, where a data source determines each page view)
- When the app starts, I want `PageViewController` to display the first page (`PageView1Controller`)

I'm comfortable with Swift, but the UIKit framework is a little daunting at the moment.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the dimensions of your UIView and UILabel? Select the view in the nib or storyboard and open the Size inspector (cmd-opt-5). You could also try printing their frames in your `viewDidLoad`. I've had problems like what you describe where I find views get zero-size frames, so they're on screen, but not visible.

Comment: Will check now, thanks Christopher....

Comment: The frame was indeed correctly-sized.  I took @DairySeeker's advice and programmatically set the background, which worked...indicating the problem has to do with the views I created in IB not displaying...which is really a different question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've said you set the PageViewController as your initial view controller but are you sure you did this correctly. It should look similar to the screenshot below.
[image: Storyboard Showing Initial view controller]

Ive just done a simple project with a page controller and then its in view did load did the following:-

```
let pagevc1 = UIViewController()
    pagevc1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    self.setViewControllers([pagevc1], direction:     UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Which seems to display fine. How are you initialising the Page1ViewController view controller?

Comment: Yes, I see the arrow...let me try programmatically setting the color and seeing what happens

Comment: Interesting...I set the color programmatically, and it is indeed red.  So the problem appears to be that the view controller isn't correctly associated with the view I (visually) created in IB.  I'm going to mark your answer as correct, though I may have to ask additional questions...thank you, DairySeeker!

Comment: Ok well if you get stuck post some code on here and ill try help you out matey :D