# UIView created in Interface Builder not rendering as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, xcode6

I'm trying to get my head around iOS development (Swift + Xcode 6), and I'm trying to figure out how what I do in the Interface Builder relates to my code.

What I've done is created `PageViewController : UIPageViewController` which, in its `viewDidLoad` method, calls `setViewControllers` to add a single view controller, an instance of `Page11ViewController : UIViewController`.

Thanks to a helpful answer on a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491691/my-uiview-isnt-rendering), I now know that `PageViewController` and `Page1ViewController` are being created successfully.  However, I am trying to design `Page1ViewController` in IB, and what's being rendered doesn't reflect the work I'm doing in IB.  In my storyboard, I have the following:

[image]

So "Page 1 View Controller Scene" contains a view that contains a label ("Page 1").  I have made "Page 1 View Controller" an instance of `Page1ViewController` by setting its class in the Identity Inspector for that view controller:

[image]

But when I run the app, I don't see my white view with a "Page 1" label; instead I see a blank red view.  Why red?  Because I did this:

```
class Page1ViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        println("Page 1 loaded")
        println("Subviews: \(view.subviews.count)")
    }
}
```

So I know that code is being executed, and the background is being set there...and the subview count printed out is 0...so I know that the view I'm constructing in my IB Storyboard is not the view that's actually getting drawn.

Here is the code from `PageViewController` that adds `Page1ViewController`:

```
class PageViewController : UIPageViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        println("Page view controller loaded")
        let page1vc = Page1ViewController()
        setViewControllers([page1vc],
            direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward,
            animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How do I attach the view I'm creating in IB to the code?

Comment: If you toggle down the arrow under the yellow "Page 1 view controller" you should see a UIView instance.  This will be automatically connected to the view controller's view property.  You don't need a UIView IBOutlet.  Can you show the code where you instantiate the page 1 view controller and add it to your page view controller?

Comment: Updated my question with the `PageViewController` code.  And yes, I see the `UIView` instance under "Page 1 View Controller" in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are instantiating an empty `Page1ViewController`, rather than loading it from your storyboard so it isn't connected to any of the objects you defined in the scene.

You should use -

```
class PageViewController : UIPageViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        println("Page view controller loaded")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil);

        let page1vc =  storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page1ViewController") as Page1ViewController // Check the Storyboard ID for your scene in the storyboard  
        setViewControllers([page1vc],
            direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm looking for...let me try this and get back to you.  Thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: Heck yeah, man, that worked like a charm!  Not only did you answer the question, but you helped me understand how this all fits together better.  Thank you.  Follow-up question: is this the best way to do it?  Is there some way I should be connecting these things in IB rather than doing it in code?  I'm at that stage where I don't know what tool to use where.

Comment: You can't directly link the page view controllers in Interface Builder - normally you would use the data source delegate to provide the view controllers as required.  Here is one tutorial - http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: Ah yes, I did read about using a data source.  I didn't go down that road because I didn't necessarily feel that it made sense in this application -- but of course I don't really understand the framework yet, so my instincts are suspect.  Thanks again for your lucid answer.